TypeError: Style frame __init__ doesn't support Styler
So I have a dataframe with multiple columns and I am converting that dataframe to excel in my first function which is beautify_output where I add colour to the entire row based on the value of the result column.
The next function is where I am facing problems, when I try to run the code, I keep getting an error whenever I try to initialise sf=StyleFrame(df). What I'm trying to do in this function is expand the width of the columns in the excel for some columns.
Here is the full code. I am on python 3.7
from styleframe import StyleFrame
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('final_output.csv')


def beatify_output(row):

 if row['result'] == 'Pass':
  return ['background-color: red'] * len(row)
 if row['result'] == 'Fail'
  return ['background-color: green'] * len(row)

df = df.style.apply(beatify_output, axis=1)

df.to_excel('my_file.xlsx',sheet_name='Sheet1')```

def expand_columns_size():
    
     len_max = 50
    
     excel_writer = 
      StyleFrame.ExcelWriter('my_file.xlsx')
    
     sf = StyleFrame(df)
    
       
     sf.set_column_width(columns=['actual_prompt', 'expected_prompt'], width=len_max)
    
     sf.to_excel(excel_writer=excel_writer)
    
     excel_writer.save()
    
expand_columns_size()


Please provide a [mcve]. As of now this code does not generate the mentioned error (StyleFrame.Excelwriter should be StyleFrame.ExcelWriter and set_column_width does not accept a sheet_name argument) so it's hard to know what is going on in your actual code.

I added my full code. Thank you for your feedback. Can you have a look now please?

The error is due to the fact that styleframe does not know how to handle pandas' styler objects as it has its own way of expressing styles.
Since you are already using styleframe it would be easier to do all the styling with it.
import pandas as pd

from styleframe import StyleFrame, Styler

df = pd.read_csv('final_output.csv')
sf = StyleFrame(df)
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['result'] == 'Pass'], Styler(bg_color="green"))
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf[sf['result'] == 'Fail'], Styler(bg_color="red"))

# If there are ONLY 'Pass'/'Fail' values in 'result' column we can use
# sf.apply_style_by_indexes(
#     indexes_to_style=sf[sf['result'] == 'Pass'],
#     styler_obj=Styler(bg_color="green"),
#     complement_style=Styler(bg_color="red")
# )

len_max = 50
sf.set_column_width(columns=['actual_prompt', 'expected_prompt'], width=len_max)
sf.to_excel('my_file.xlsx').close()  # or .save() if close() raises an AttributeError

outputs


Hey man, really appreciate it. It works as you've shown here. Just one more small thing, is there a way to dynamically adjust the width of each column based on it's max value?. Also, can you point me towards some tutorials with StyleFrame as my project will need a lot of it. Thanks again! You're a saviour

@TanmaySharma Instead of using set_column_width, pass best_fit=['actual_prompt', 'expected_prompt'] to to_excel. It is a best-effort attempt using a hardcoded formula and is dependent on a few variables such as the font used as noted in the docs.

@TanmaySharma As for tutorials, you can go over some basic examples and the entire API docs
